# functions of avg and count

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL have some already made functions like `AVG()` and `COUNT()`, and I want to know the code of those 2 functions, so I can make other similar functions but with extra conditions. By wanting the code, I don't mean how to use them in SQL query, but I mean the basic written function of avg and count.

And by the way, MS access contains pre made functions, that can't be used in MySQL, and I want to make some of them.

Comment: Here ya go: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/guided-tour.html  enjoy !

Comment: mysql has many pre-defined functions..can you be more clear exactly which method you want to implement

Comment: @Drew I will try, but now you mentioned, and I am interested in both methods. How can I make a avg() function in UDF and not thru Btree ?